# Matching two Lists of different types together

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have two tables, each with their own model...

```
    class FamilyMan
    { 
        public int family_ID {get; set;}

        public string name {get; set;}
        public string fav_color {get; set;}
    }

    class BusinessMan
    {
        public int work_ID {get; set;}

        public string name {get; set;}
        public string fav_color {get; set;}

        //unrelated data etc
        public string job_title {get; set;}
    }
```

... and I want to be able to match up all FamilyMans to the matching BusinessMans based on `name` and `fav_color`.

I currently have something like:

```
    //fill lists from database
    var family_list = dbContext.FamilyMen.ToList();
    var busy_list = dbContext.BusinessMen.ToList();
    //create empty dict for matching the two types
    var matches = new Dict<FamilyMan, BusinessMan>();


    foreach (FamilyMan fam_man in family_list) {
        foreach (BusinessMan busy_man in busy_list) {
            //if both names and colors match, consider them a matching
            //object and add them each to the dict
            if (fam_man.name == busy_man.name &&
                    fam_man.color == busy_man.color) {
                matches_MtO[fam_man] = busy_man;
            }
        }
    }
```

but it takes quite a time to complete.

I've also looked at looping over one list with a `foreach` and then using LINQs FirstOrDefault to match them, but the efficiency seems about the same.

**Is there a better way to go about matching `FamilyMan`s and `BusinessMan`s together?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use LINQ's join syntax.  This will enable the backend database to do the matching, and return only the result.

In order to enable a join on a composite key, follow the [MSDN guidance here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907099.aspx)

```
var query = from fm in dbContext.FamilyMen
            join bm in dbContext.BusinessMen on 
                new { bm.name, bm.color } equals new { fm.name, fm.color }
            select new {
               FamilyMan = fm,
               BusinessMan = bm
            };

var resultList = query.ToList();
```

Comment: I had to add matching names to the first two anonymous objects, `Name` and `Color`, respectively, and it seemed to work instantly. This works really well, I'll just give @Gerve  a minute to fix his query to solve the `Expression Expected` issue if it's possible, otherwise I'll accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: "matching names" being something like `new { Name = bm.name, Color = bm.color }` for both the objects. From the docs you linked: `For example, if the Orders table and OrderDetails table each used different names for their columns, you could create composite keys by assigning identical names in the anonymous types:` Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Would a linq query like this be faster:

```
var matches = (
    from f in family_list
    join b in busy_list
    on f.color == b.color
    && f.name == b.name
    select new {f, b}
);
```

Comment: after ` ... == b.color` the `&&` doesn't seem to work. `Expression Expected`

Answer (score 2):

Your are looping through both lists, which is O(N-squared).

Once an item is matched, it does not have to be matched again.  You could remove matched items from the list, reducing the unnecessary comparisons.

Better yet, since you are matching on two properties being identical, you could build a dictionary using a hash representing the combined properties as the key.  Then you could loop through the keys of family_list_dictionary and just look for a matching key in busy_list_dictionary.

Comment: I've never worked with hashes before, do you have any good examples offhand? Would I loop through both tables, pulling the two properties, convert them to a hash somehow, save the hash to a list, then come through the hash list and compare the family hashes to the business hashes?

Comment: I am not at a computer right now. I can give you a detailed example in a few hours.

Comment: Don't worry about it, if you don't want, I found a working answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14283717/541208 . I would like to learn how to do something like that, but no worries.

Comment: @Eric, if you'd be willing to, I'd still like to see how you would go about doing it for the sake of just learning something new...